# Cálculo relacional en una biblioteca

Tags: base-de-datos, cálculo-relacional

Un biblioteca tiene dos bases de datos. Con un asterisco * aparecen las claves primarias de las relaciones:

```
Prestamo
-------
*Persona
*Libro
*FechaPrestamo
FechaRetornoPredecido
Fecha Retorno

Retraso
-------
*Persona
*Libro
*FechaPrestamo
pénalizacionRetraso
```

¿Cómo expresar en cálculo relacional las personas que nadie han devuelvo un libro con un retraso?

He dicho que Π<sub>people</sub>(Prestamo)÷Π<sub>livre</sub>(Retraso) expressa las personas que nadie han devuelvo un libro con un retraso pero no soy seguro...

¿Cómo hacer lo mismo pero en cálculo relacional?

```
{t.Persona|Retraso(t)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es necesaria la segunda tabla, debes de definir que es lo que estas almacenando. No muestras el lenguaje ni tampoco la base de datos para poder ayudarte.

Si no estás tomando en cuenta la fecha actual, solamente tienes que validar si tienes algún registro en la segunda tabla.
Si estás comparando un usuario en específico, entonces tienes que validar si existe esa persona.

Saludos,